# Realizar mapeamento hibernate (annotations) de chave estrangeira sendo também a primária

Tags: java, hibernate

Quero realizar o mapeamento no padrão annotations do hibernate de minha classe, sendo o relacionamento um-para-um entre as tabelas, e a chave primária de uma é estrangeira e primária na outra, sendo que a segunda não faz parte da primeira, alguém poderia me ajudar?